# Could not get the Download path

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-download-manager

I am downloading a pdf file using URL with DownloadManager. The file is downloading successfully, with the provided link/URL. The status is also visible in notifications, and after downloading, pdf can be opened, and viewed. I am also setting the file destination using below code:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"pdf1.pdf");
```

Now, the problem is, file is downloading, but I couldn't find the file in my downloads folder. I basically want to Toast out the path of my downloaded file.
Here is my entire code:

```
downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"pdf1.pdf");

        Long ref = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

What are the changes that I need to do, to get the path of the downloaded file?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why not log  Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD to check the path

Answer (score 0):

Try to ask for permissions, read and write, before storing your data

Comment: I have already given permissions for both read and write as well as internet. But still for some reason it’s crashing when I try to give it a destination.

Comment: Check if the file `pdf1.pdf` exists, else try to create the file  before using it to store your pdf. You can also add a Toast to display the error you get.